# GetQueuedCompletionStatus() - what is a "completion packet"

Tags: c, winapi, winsock

There is a function GetQueuedCompletionStatus  and its description with MSDN:

> Attempts to dequeue an I/O completion packet from the specified I/O
> completion port. If there is no completion packet queued, the function
> waits for a pending I/O operation associated with the completion port
> to complete.

I thought I understood how it works, but today I realized that I didn't understand how it works.

What is meant by - "completion packet" ?

I will give an example: I am doing sending a message "my request" to the server using WSASend and completion ports:

1. I create a socket.
2. I make a connection to the server: WSAConnect()
3. Here I put a breakpoint: I pull out the wire from the network card, now I have no Internet on my computer.
4. Now I am calling the WSASend() function. WSASend() function ends successfully! Okay, this is probably due to asynchrony.
5. Next, I call the GetQueuedCompletionStatus() function - and it succeeds too !! Why ???

The GetQueuedCompletionStatus() function should get from the completion port queue a READY task to send my message to the server, BUT there is no Internet on the computer and sending my message shouldn't happen - how then can this be?

Or what then is meant by - "completion packet from the specified I/O completion port."

Something I'm completely confused.

Comment: this is [`IOP_MINI_COMPLETION_PACKET`](https://test.timeback18.com/wrk12/iomgr_8h-source.html#l00399), frequetly this is part or [`IRP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_irp) - look in *wdm.h* - `PacketType` (*Minipacket type* ) and `ListEntry` ( *List entry - used to queue the packet to completion queue, among others.* ) possible this is `IO_MINI_COMPLETION_PACKET_USER` (allocated with `IoAllocateMiniCompletionPacket` and inserted via `IoSetIoCompletionEx` )

Comment: Basically this is a case of Kernel level details leaking in to user space. The reality is that it's still treated as an `OVERLAPPED`

Comment: @Mgetz really any completion packet type not related to `OVERLAPPED`. in packet exist `ApcContext` member - where saved what is passed to I/O call in native api. win32 layer pass pointer to `OVERLAPPED` in place `ApcContext`. when packed dequeued we get back pointer `ApcContext`

Comment: @RbMm fair enough... it's still a kernel level implementation detail leaking through and not really relevant information to the user of that API IMO. In this case it clearly caused confusion when it wasn't necessary.

Comment: GetQueuedCompletionStatus successfully retrieved a completion packet. The completion packet is the completion of the WSASend. You can then look at the completion packet to see that "Oh, WSASend says that it failed." (You ask someone to wait for a letter to arrive and bring it to you. They wait, and hey look a letter arrived, and they bring it to you. They succeeded. You open the letter, and it's a rejection letter. You are sad, but you can't blame the person who brought the letter to you. They did their job successfully.)

Comment: @Raymond Chen, But in my scenario, WSASend did not report a failure the connect. Vice versa! WSASend reported success.

Comment: Maybe the send is waiting in a buffer and hasn't been put on the wire yet.

Comment: it is very likely that it was. It was my mistake to think that the function GetQueuedCompletionStatus reports sending WSASend over the network. However, this was not the case. The function GetQueuedCompletionStatus  only reports that it has sent the task to be sent, and not that the message was sent over the network.

Comment: GetQueuedCompletionStatus is returning the result of the WSASend. Whether WSASend succeeded or failed is not GetQueuedCompletionStatus's concern. GetQueuedCompletionStatus is just the delivery guy.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, But then the problem arises of what to do if WSASend and GetQueuedCompletionStatus  report success and at this moment the connection is broken. Who can tell me that the connection was broken and that no data was actually not transmitted? :)

Comment: That's a networking question, unrelated to GetQueuedCompletionStatus. The same question applies to synchronous non-overlapped sockets. (The WSASend documentation even says "Note: The successful completion of a WSASend does not indicate that the data was successfully delivered.")

Comment: @Optimus1 TCP is resilient, it is designed to handle network outages. Pulling the cable out does not break the connection immediately, there is a delay. If you plug the cable back in within a certain time, the connection will be restored automatically. In the meantime, outgoing data is buffered.

Answer (score 1):

“Completion port” refers to [overlapped IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports?redirectedfrom=MSDN) – not to the network port or socket port. They are ways to receive the results of asynchronous reads, writes, etc…

Writes can succeed due to buffering, a flush would be required to force the write to the wire. Many details also depends upon the specific type of socket (TCP, UDP, IP, listener, client, etc…)

You should probably start with synchronous calls, then add overlapped once you feel comfortable with synchronous.

Comment: You wrote "They are ways to receive the results of asynchronous reads, writes". Main question: Results writes - where? In my case, to some buffer of the network card?

Comment: When using overlapped IO with Winsock, the data is still written or read from the buffers you provide (e.g.: `lpBuffers` in `WSARead`) - it just doesn't happen immediately.  You have to wait for the asynchronous read/write to complete (e.g.: with `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents`).

Comment: Unless you are passing a `WSAOVERLAPPED` to a function, you *are not* doing overlapped IO and should ignore it.  If you are passing a `WSAOVERLAPPED` to a function, consider not doing that for now and rely upon synchronous reads and writes.

Comment: @Optimus1 - in any case - this is only small chunk of memory - usually `IRP` or  `IOP_MINI_COMPLETION_PACKET`. in your case - packet is part of `IRP`

Comment: @Mitch, I'm using the completion ports method, why why should i use WSAWaitForMultipleEvents ?

Comment: Completion ports are an alternative to `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` - you would not use them simultaneously.

Comment: @Mitch, And I don't use them at the same time. You wrote this about WSAWaitForMultipleEvents :)

Comment: "RbMm, Thanks. For me, the problem is as follows, the GetQueuedCompletionStatus function announced that it was ready to send a message to the server and removed the completion packet from the completion port queue. BUT, the message was not actually sent as the link was disconnected. And this is the problem, that it is not clear how to determine that there is no connection, because after WSASendI will call WSARecv, and since there is no connection, I can wait for a response from the server indefinitely.

Comment: As an example, yes.  The questions are these: Are you intending to use overlapped IO? Why do you think that unplugging a network card will cause a socket to break?  If you want to detect loss of communication, you would need to use a heartbeat mechanism.

Comment: Overlapped completion refers only to the success or failure of the asynchronous function call - no judgement can be made about whether the data got to the server.  With some protocols (UDP, IP, etc...) - it is not possible to say whether the data was delivered.

Comment: @Optimus1 `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` - not *announced that it was ready to send a message to the server*. this simply say that your I/O operation completed. nothing more. all this absolute unrelated to any server, internet connection, etc

Answer (score 1):

The completion packet is the LPOVERLAPPED that you pass to an IOCP-capable function. If you are using IOCP so long as the original function returns ERROR_IO_PENDING that OVERLAPPED instance needs to remain good until you retrieve confirmation of the original function's completion (whether successful or not). The IOCP system does not copy the contents of the OVERLAPPED structure, instead the address is saved and then returned by GetQueuedCompletionStatus. If the original function returns something other than ERROR_IO_PENDING then the packet is not queued to the completion port and can be released immediately.

Comment: This is not overlapped. In case packet from I/O request - packet is IRP, and here saved pointer passed to I/O request, in case win32 i/o api used - this pointer is pointer to overlapped